# Under the hood of Send function in masstranssit

Tags: .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm trying to send command to rabbitMQ  by masstransit while i know difference between send and publish , defined a direct exchange but use Send to transit that message after that i'm getting error that "Exchange name" received fanout but current is direct .

Does Send makes exchange to fanout type?

```
          config.ReceiveEndpoint("test-consumer", consumer =>
            {
                consumer.Lazy = true;
                consumer.Consumer<TestConsumer>();
                consumer.Durable = true;
                consumer.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;

                consumer.Bind("MyExchange", ex =>
               {

                   ex.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Direct;
                   ex.RoutingKey = "reza";
               });
                //binding type from test-consumer exchange to test-consumer queue
                // consumer.ExchangeType = "direct";
            });
var endPoint = await bus.GetSendEndpoint(new Uri("exchange:MyExchange"));

         var send3 = rezEndPoint.Send(new Test { Messaged = "sent from myExchange" },h=> { h.SetRoutingKey("reze"); } );
```

Comment: Your RabbitMQ exchange is probably setup incorrectly. You need to go in to your RabbitMQ instance and check that your exchange is set to "Type" direct. I believe they default to fanout when creating a new exchange, it's easy to forget to change it.

Comment: @jandrew MassTransit takes care of creating exchanges for you, so as soon as it's not created manually, the exchange should be correctly configured by the library.

Comment: @jandrew as you can see my exchange configuration is created in "direct" type , but what i think is "send" would send as "fanout" in under its hood . 
My question is about send command that how it would send command to rabbitMQ

Answer (score 0):

Since you are specifying the exchange type as *direct* in the consumer, you need to also set that via the send endpoint:

```
var endPoint = await bus.GetSendEndpoint(new Uri("exchange:MyExchange?type=direct"));
```

Comment: thank you  @Chris ,  It doesn't mentioned anywhere in MassTransit documents , at least i didn't see , anyway after that change you mentioned , exception  "exchange is direct but current is fanout" doesn't appears but my ** message also has not received by consumer **

Comment: That would mean your TestConsumer doesn't consume the message type that was sent to that exchange.